# SSH Port Forwarding on a Linksys EA7500 - how would I go about setting it up?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ssh, port-forwarding

Trying to setup SSH ability to an Ubuntu 19.10 server....

I have an EA7500. I need to know what to put for start/end port and device ip#. Local IP is 192.169.1.142. For context, [here's a link to the portforward.com article](https://portforward.com/linksys). SSH is running on port 22, which I don't care if it needs to be changed or not, whatever you guys suggest. I've never done any port forwarding before, how would I fill in the fields?

Comment: Do you need the public IP to help me or no?

Comment: **_NEVER_ share your public [WAN] IP online.**  _Start_ and _End_ port is for port range forwarding, you need single port forwarding.  Port range would be when you need to forward several ports in sequential order (i.e. `3000-3010`).  _DO NOT forward WAN-side port `22`_.. pick an extremely high port number (>`50000`, but <`65535`, as port scanners generally don't scan all 65,535 ports, so the higher the better) for the WAN-side port and forward that to the LAN-side port the SSH server is running on.  For example, any in WAN on port `53815` to `192.168.0.2` on port `22`

Comment: Why do you go to port range forwarding when you want single port forwarding :-\

Comment: @JW0914 ok.. assuming i set it at XXXXX, what do i put for internal port/external port/device ip#? feel free to put it in the answer